# Implications of equal Intergrations of two CDF

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two positive random variables with CDF $F_X$ and $F_Y$, respectively. Also, let $X$ and $Y$ be defined over $(0,\infty)$, and $F_X$ and $F_Y$ are continuous. We know that The mean of two random variables are equal, say $E_X = E_Y$.

Since both are positive. We have,

$$E_X = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X(t)) ~dt = \int_0^\infty (1-F_Y(t)) ~dt = E_Y$$

What can we say more about $F_X$ and $F_Y$? (some what rigorously), and why are they (not) equal ?

My first guess would be that if we move the right integral over to the other side and define a function $F_D= F_Y-F_X$ and since the integration is equal to zero and both are continuous then we might say that $F_D$ is equal to zero except at points with zero measure. Is this accurate? and what can we say about the random variables $X$ and $Y$ in this case?

Comment: I'm afraid we cannot say much more than $X$ and $Y$ having the same expectation. Their higher moments are not necessarily equal. Example is if $X\sim \exp(1)$ and $Y \sim G(2,2)$ (Gamma). They have the same expectation but not the same variance.

Comment: Even if you had all moments you might not always be able to know everything about $F$. The lognormal distribution is an example of a distribution that is not defined uniquely by its moments.